# Should I use "having internship" or "the internship"?

Tags: articles, verb-usage

I wanted to write something like this :

> I've decided to not change my questionnaire, because **the internship** abroad is a great opportunity to improve my English.

but I am very unsure about "the internship" Will it be better to write this : 
".. because having internship abroad is ... "

Which one sound more natural to native speakers and why ?

Comment: In either case, you need a determiner before *internship*.  For example, "having *an* internship abroad" or "having *this* internship abroad."

Answer (score 2):

In your example, since it is a single *internship*, you should use some sort of article or modifier depending on context

> the internship
>   an internship
>   my internship

in the case of multiple *internships*, the article or modifier is not necessary

> because *(having)* internship**s** abroad **are** a great opportunity to improve my English.

is correct and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on whether the **internship** in the context is defined earlier

In case the reader/listener already knows which internship the speaker is mentioning then

> ...because **the internship** abroad is a...

If the internship is referring to a general term then,

> ...because **an internship** abroad is a...
>    ...because **having internship** abroad is a...

both can work.